# Custom serialization and deserialization with pinia in nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3, pinia

I am working with Nuxt3 and Pinia. I love how the majority of the SSR hastle is managed automatically for you. However, I have a custom class that makes my life a lot easier. It has some convenient methods, but these cannot be serialized. Now the class can be very easily serialized and deserialized by calling toJSON, and subsequently passing the result to the constructor (to deserialize). My problem is, how do I tell  Nuxt to do this. Ideally it should call toJSON right before running everything through devalue and it should run the constructor right after reinitiating the Pinia stores (but before the actual hydration, because it will need my custom class).

I played around with hooks to which i connected via a plugin. However I don't really know which hook to use exactly as they do not seem to represent the lifecycle steps I am after. Also I had trouble loading the store in the hook callback. So that did not work for me.